# Iterating over strings in list in python

Tags: python, iterator

```
reads = { '1': 'A', '2': 'B', '3': 'C', '4': 'D', '5': 'E', '6': 'F' }`
readOrder = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']`
```

How can I iterate over string like in `readOrder`:

```
a = []
for i in readOrder():
    a.append(reads[i],reads[i+1])

''.join(a)

print a
```

So I can get:

```
'ABBCCDDEEF'
```

This way works, but there must be an easy way to do it with a for loop I guess:

```
a = [reads[0] + reads[1], reads[1] + reads[2], 
     reads[2] + reads[3], reads[3] + reads[4]]
print ''.join(a)
```

Comment: So you want to take a dictionary and make a string with all of its keys twice except for the first and last?

Comment: I just use it for an example. The idea is to loop over a list that can can take an element and the element after at the same time. This is simple enough for numbers, and I want it to be simple enough for strings :)

Comment: Well, I can't post an answer anymore, so my solution was:
`''.join([reads.get(i, "") + reads.get(str(int(i)+1), "") for i in readOrder])`

Comment: Perhaps better than the solution above because it uses the readorder if you need a particular order: ''.join([reads[y] for x in zip(readOrder, readOrder[1:]) for y in x])

Comment: @FMc: If you scroll down to the worse answers, it’s the same thing, yeah. Also, read the comment: “The idea is to loop over a list that [can] take an element and the element after at the same time.”

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
for i,key in enumerate(readOrder):
 a.append(reads[key])
 if i != 0 and i != len(readOrder) - 1:
   a.append(reads[key])
''.join(a)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this?  (Revised for strings)

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-2.7/bin/python

reads = { '1': 'A', '2': 'B', '3': 'C', '4': 'D', '5': 'E', '6': 'F' }

readOrder = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

a = []
for indexno, index_str in enumerate(readOrder[:-1]):
    index_str_p1 = readOrder[indexno + 1]
    a.append(reads[index_str])
    a.append(reads[index_str_p1])

print a
print ''.join(a)
```

Comment: OK, why the downvote?  You could at least tersely comment on what's wrong with it.  It gives exactly the output the OP requested.